# What do the numbers mean in the reasons section in proof sequences?

Tags: notation, proof-explanation

```
Prove: p V q and not p => q

solution:

statements                Reasons
1. p V q                  Given
2. not p                  Given
3. not (not p) V q        Double Negation, 1
4. not p ->               implication, 3
5. q                      Modus Ponens, 4,2
```

Answer (score 1):

They are references to earlier steps in the proof, which you can see have been numbered. For example:

```
3. not (not p) V q        Double Negation, 1
```

means that both `Double Negation` and step 1,

```
1. p V q                  Given
```

are being cited as reasons for statement 3 to be true.

Comment: Glad to help! After a while, if this answer is satisfactory, you'll have the option of clicking a checkmark on the left of my answer to indicate it is your "accepted" answer.

Comment: @smork: You may also follow the recommended practice of having the question in  the body of your post and not just  in the title.